# How to remove SCNNode when Tap on it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit, scnnode

I have Creat Cubes using SceneView and i want to disappear cube on which Tap action. How can achieve it?

Here is my code to create Cube

```
     SCNBox *Box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:2.0 height:2.0 length:2.0 
     chamferRadius:Radius];


     Box.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor whiteColor];
     SCNNode *cubeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:Box];
     [ArrBoxNode addObject:cubeNode];

     self.sceneView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
     self.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor grayColor];

     cubeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(4,0,0);

     [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cubeNode];
     self.sceneView.scene = scene;
     [self.sceneView sizeToFit];




 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.sceneView];
      SCNHitTestResult *hitTestResult = [[self.sceneView 
      hitTest:touchPoint options:nil] firstObject];
      SCNNode *hitNode = hitTestResult.node;

      for (SCNNode *node in ArrBoxNode) {
         [node removeFromParentNode];
   } 
 }
```

but I'm not able to remove Node from Tap action. Can you please help me, and give better suggestions, thank you... :)

Comment: try with `[hitNode removeFromParentNode];` and let me know

Comment: this works but when i add new cube its not working

Comment: first check if you are touching in that object, maybe is that what is happening you need to touch the object that you need to remove, let me know

Comment: Working bro.thanks a lot.i found one issue.can you plz tell?

Comment: i am doing explosion animation on tap event.when i remove node,animation not working.plz check

Comment: SCNParticleSystem * particleSystem = [SCNParticleSystem particleSystemNamed:@"ExplosionAnimation" inDirectory:nil];
            
            
            [hitNode addParticleSystem:particleSystem];

Comment: You are removing the node and adding the explosion animation, that is why don't work, please check adding the animation without removing the hitNode, and let me know , by the way i will answer your question ok?

Comment: actually after animation,i am removing node

Comment: @ReinierMelian any other good tutorials for scenekit to learn more?can you plz provide ?

Comment: hello @ReinierMelian can you please check this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095691/how-to-check-which-scnnode-is-tapped-in-scenekit-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove the node you are touching using `[hitNode removeFromParentNode];`

**Code**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.sceneView];
    SCNHitTestResult *hitTestResult = [[self.sceneView hitTest:touchPoint options:nil] firstObject];
    SCNNode *hitNode = hitTestResult.node;
    [hitNode removeFromParentNode];
}
```