# detect which node clicked on 3D model

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have 3D model and want to click on specific node on this model to create some action. My model is group of nodes; every node hasn't chilled node, I want to click on one of the nodes to excuse some action and click on another node to excuse differ action; how can detect which node is click on my model?

Comment: check this answer is objectiveC but i think you can translate it to swift easily https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977468/how-to-remove-scnnode-when-tap-on-it/47979107#47979107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hitTest(_:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest) from [SCNSceneRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer) to detect 3D objects touched from 2D Point.

It will return an array of [SCNHitTestResult](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnhittestresult) which contain a `node` property.

Comment: its work with this code                                                                                  `guard let currentTouchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self.sceneView), let hitTestResultNode = self.sceneView.hitTest(currentTouchLocation, options: nil).first else {return}
   // print(hitTestResultNode.node.name)
    if hitTestResultNode.node.name == "Hair"{
        print("hair node is clicked ")
    }else if hitTestResultNode.node.name == "_"{
        print("eye is clicked ")
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You should read some info about SceneKit hit-testing methods and following [hit-test method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522929-hittest).

```
func registerGestureRecognizer() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(detectNode))
    self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func detectNode(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let sceneView = sender.view as! ARSCNView
    let location = sender.location(in: sceneView)
    let results = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: [SCNHitTestOption.searchMode : 1])

    for result in results.filter( { $0.node.name != nil }) {
        if result.node.name == "Your node name" {
            // excuse some actions
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!